# Server not booting after 16.04 upgrade (not pinging)

Tags: ubuntu, boot, ovh

Yesterday I upgraded my server to 16.04, all fine and when I rebooted the server has rebooted to rescue.
I fixed packaging conflicts via `apt-get autoremove``apt-get upgrade` etc...
I also tryed to repair grub mounting my hd in /mnt and working with chroot, it seems all ok.
When I try to reboot from hard drive (I've a administration panel because i'm on OVH server), the server ping for 1 second.
After some minutes I receive this mail from OVH support:
*"The server has started (login is requested on the screen) 
but inaccessible by the network (not pinging).
A restart on the OVH Kernel ('netboot') does not correct the problem."*

After that the server is rebooted in rescue mode from OVH.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

For someone with the same problem I found the solution in this log file 
**/mnt/var/log/dmesg** (server boot log) and almost at the end I found that the disk was mounted in readonly during boot (IDK Why).

So fixed with a fsck and a touch /forcefsck and rebooted from HD.

All working